# Trouble implementing material in Spark AR

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am new to spark AR studio. I have built an effect, Im using particle system but when I add some material this particle system gets invisible. I dont know how to figured out

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details on your problem? Include screenshots of your material and emitter inspector panels.

Comment: Check your material opacity?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a material in your video but then you have to have to select that material and apply a texture to it.